# Call templates within xsl:result-document

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to generate multiple files using the following codes:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Content[(@index &gt; 1) and (string-length(Item[1]) != 0) and (string-length(Item[2]) = 0)]">


    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('output1/',@Item[1],'.html')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  
    <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
             <html><body>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="Content" mode="create" />
             </body></html>
     </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

Regardless of my XML file and the "create" template which are actually irrelevant at this point, my program simply does not call the template within the body tags. When I debug the program in Eclipse, my codes did not go inside and run whatever is enclosed by the result-document tags.

****The codes are able to generate multiple files with the desired file names. But they do not have anything within the body tags.

Also, if I change the codes to:

```
        <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
             <html><body>
                   <xsl:value-of select="$filename"/>
             </body></html>
     </xsl:result-document>
```

It was able to generate multiple files with the file names in the body tags.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:apply-templates/@select` attribute should select against the input XML document.  It should look something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="create" />
```

As you have it, the `xsl:apply-templates` is looking for and not finding a `filename` element at the current node.

### **Update per OP edit of the XSLT:**

You don't want to select `Content` if it is `Content` that you're iterating over; select `.`, the current node, instead.

You'll also have to be sure to have a template that matches against `Content` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="Content" mode="create">
  Output something here
</xsl:template>
```

**Finally, the fact that your `xsl:for-each` is within a template matching `/` and then iterating over `Content` children looks suspect.**  There can only be one root node in well-formed XML.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from my original codes. I have targeted it to the XML document now but still nothing was generated..

Comment: My template is <xsl:template match="Content" mode="create">

Comment: Hm actually I think there's probably something wrong with my apply-template. If I change it to call-template and hard code the xpath in my template the codes work...

Comment: As I state in my answer, if your (corrected) source now has `<xsl:apply-templates select="Content" mode="create" />`, it's not going to work; it'll have to select `.` instead.  Also, attend to ***each*** of the points in my answer carefully; *they are all important.*